Copy set amount of lines from 1 file to an other file
I have a file that has a couple 100 lines in it. I only want to keep a portion of it, and discard the rest. First I build a function that gives me the row number where the file should really end on by using this:
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('
findstr /n /c:"(search term)" "(source file location and name)"
') do set start=%%a
SET /A truestart=%start%-1

This gives me a row value that is 1 above the searched term and that is exactly what I want.
E.g. the value is 600 so it copies rows 1 to 599 to a different file and ignores row 600 to end document.
I tried looking for a solution thinking I should be using a form of loop to copy the lines 1 by one to a new file until specified line is reached.
I found this loop on this page that supposed to do what I want:
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: set counter
set c=0
for /f "delims=|" %%i in ("source file location and name") do (
:: increment counter for each line read
  set /a c=!c!+1
  if !c! leq %truestart% echo %%i >> "destination file location and name"
)

This give me a new file, but it copies only the source file location and name to the destination file and not the content in the source.
So I know I am missing something reading out the source per line but I can't figure out what.
I also tried using more:
more /e /p +%truestart% "source file location and name" > "destination file location and name"

This gives me the opposite, this displays only the part what I want to take out and leaves out what I actually want.

Don't use invalid labels as comment identifier. There is a REM command for that. Invalid labels within a code block/loop tend to do unexpected things (like skipping lines)

Read for /? again: your syntax doesn't evaluate the file's content, but the literal string (filename). See the usebackq operator.

The set command can be shortened to set /a c+=1

Also, in the first example you submitted, you could simplify set start=%%a, followed after the loop by SET /A truestart=%start%-1, by using just set /a truestart = %%a - 1.

Thanks for the suggestions. I cleaned it up a bit based on your suggestions.
After a bit of research I found a better workaround.
I managed to get the result I wanted trough powershell:
@echo off

rem set final line
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('
findstr /n /c:"(search term)" "(source document)"
') do set /a end=%%a-2

set "inputFile="(source document)""
set "outputFile="(destination document)""
 
powershell -Command "Get-Content -Path '%inputFile%' -TotalCount %end% | Set-Content -Path '%outputFile%'"

This gives me exactly the result I want.

If you want the above to be correct, i.e. for the PowerShell -Command to remain unchanged, you must change set "inputFile="(source document)"" and set "outputFile="(destination document)"" to be Set "inputFile=(source document)" and Set "outputFile=(destination document)" respectively. Otherwise the nested doublequotes will break to parsed command passed to powershell.exe.
